# Link in Rich Text box is not clickable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms and I was wandering why my link in the rich text box is not executing with my default browser. I have created a LinkClicked eventy and added an Event handler and I am still getting an error. Hre is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "https://something.com/" + textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
        }
    }
```

When I run this I get an error saying

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LinkClickedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

What can I do to fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does *I have created a LinkClicked eventy and added an Event handler* implies? Can you describe the procedure? What Framework and VisualStudio versions are you using? Btw, this is the fourth question you post related to the same exact topic.

Comment: Doubtful. The posted code is fine. You must have a typo in the real code..